# Why am I getting a parse error on my css?

Tags: css

W3 is giving me a parse error on line 314 of my css. I will paste the error and then my CSS below. Line 314 is the very last line. Visual studio code is also giving me a red line on line 315 that has nothing, its say

> } expectedcss(css-rcurlyexpected)

Even when I add it, it is still not valid.

```
URI : style.css
314     Parse Error
314     Parse Error
314     Parse Error
```

CSS

```
/* #### navbar #### */
.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: var(--nero);
    width: 100%;
}
.brand-and-toggler{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
.navbar-brand{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: var(--poppins);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar-toggler{
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: var(--transition);
}
.navbar-toggler:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.navbar-collapse{
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: var(--transition);
}
.nav-item{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-item::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--green);
    transition: var(--transition);
}
.nav-item:hover::after{
    width: 100px;
}
.nav-link{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    transition: var(--transition);
}
.nav-link:hover{
    color: var(--green);
}
.nav-active .nav-link{
    color: var(--green);
}

/*** show nav class ***/
.showNav{
    height: 385px;
}

/* #### HOME PAGE #### */
.home{
    padding: 5rem 0 2.5rem 0;
}
.home .row > div{
    height: 60vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid var(--nero);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 2rem 0;
}
.home .row-left{
    text-align: center;
}
.home .row-left h3{
    color: var(--green);
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.home .row-left h1{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: var(--poppins);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.home .row-left h1 span{
    color: var(--green);
}
.home .row-left h2{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: var(--poppins);
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.home-pg-btn{
    display: flex;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
.home-pg-btn button{
    padding: 0.8rem;
    margin-right: 0.6rem;
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
}
.home-pg-btn button:first-child{
    border-color: var(--green);
}
.home-pg-btn button:last-child{
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
.home .img-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.home .img-border{
    background: var(--nero);
    width: 245px;
    height: 245px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/* #### footer #### */
.footer{
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #252525;
}
.footer-title{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-family: var(--poppins);
    font-weight: 700;
}
.footer .col{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
.footer .col:first-child .text{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.social-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.social-links a{
    background: var(--nero);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
    transition: var(--transition);
}
.social-links a:hover{
    background: var(--green);
}
.footer-links a{
    display: block;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 0.2rem 0;
    transition: var(--transition);
}
.footer-links a .fas{
    display: none;
}
.footer-links a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
.footer .col:last-child div{
    padding: 0.2rem 0;
}
.footer .col:last-child .fas{
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
.footer-text .text{
    text-align: center;
}






/* #### Media Queries #### */
@media screen and (min-width: 500px){
    /* home page */
    .home .row-left h1{
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .home .row-left h2{
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    .home-pg-btn button{
        padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    }
    .home .img-container{
        width: 320px;
        height: 320px;
    }
    .home .img-border{
        width: 325px;
        height: 325px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    /* footer */
    .footer .row{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 992px){
        /* navbar section */
        .navbar-toggler{
            display: none;
        }
        .navbar .container{
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .navbar-nav{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }
        .navbar-collapse{
            height: 100%;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
        }
        .brand-and-toggler{
            flex: 0 0 100px;
        }
        .nav-item{
            margin: 0 0.5rem;
        }
        .nav-link{
            font-size: 1rem;
        }
    
        /* home page */
        .home .row{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 2rem;
        }
        .home .row > div{
            height: calc(100vh - 73px);
            border: none;
            margin: 0;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }
        .home .row-left{
            text-align: left;
        }
        .home .img-container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: unset;
        }
        .home .img-border{
            height: 90%;
            width: 100%;
            transition: var(--transition);
            border-radius: unset;
            background: transparent;
        }
        .home .img-border:hover{
            transform: translateY(-14px);
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
            /* footer */
            .footer .row{
                grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
            }
            .footer .row .col{
                text-align: left;
            }
            .footer .col:first-child .text{
                margin: 0;
            }
            .social-links{
                justify-content: flex-start;
            }
            .footer-links a .fas{
                display: inline-block;
            }
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Add two Brackets to the end to close your two last media screens declarations.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot 3 closing brakets. One for each media query , paste this code and compare

```css
/* #### navbar #### */
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--nero);
  width: 100%;
}

.brand-and-toggler {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: var(--poppins);
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  background: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.navbar-toggler:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.nav-item {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: var(--green);
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.nav-item:hover::after {
  width: 100px;
}

.nav-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: var(--green);
}

.nav-active .nav-link {
  color: var(--green);
}

/*** show nav class ***/
.showNav {
  height: 385px;
}

/* #### HOME PAGE #### */
.home {
  padding: 5rem 0 2.5rem 0;
}

.home .row > div {
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid var(--nero);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.home .row-left {
  text-align: center;
}

.home .row-left h3 {
  color: var(--green);
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.home .row-left h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: var(--poppins);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.home .row-left h1 span {
  color: var(--green);
}

.home .row-left h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: var(--poppins);
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.home-pg-btn {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.home-pg-btn button {
  padding: 0.8rem;
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
  border: 1px solid #F7F7F7;
}

.home-pg-btn button:first-child {
  border-color: var(--green);
}

.home-pg-btn button:last-child {
  background: transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.home .img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.home .img-border {
  background: var(--nero);
  width: 245px;
  height: 245px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* #### footer #### */
.footer {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
  border-top: 1.5px solid #252525;
}

.footer-title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-family: var(--poppins);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.footer .col {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.footer .col:first-child .text {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.social-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-links a {
  background: var(--nero);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.social-links a:hover {
  background: var(--green);
}

.footer-links a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 0.2rem 0;
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.footer-links a .fas {
  display: none;
}

.footer-links a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.footer .col:last-child div {
  padding: 0.2rem 0;
}

.footer .col:last-child .fas {
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.footer-text .text {
  text-align: center;
}


/* #### Media Queries #### */
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  /* home page */
  .home .row-left h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }

  .home .row-left h2 {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }

  .home-pg-btn button {
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  }

  .home .img-container {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
  }

  .home .img-border {
    width: 325px;
    height: 325px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* footer */
  .footer .row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  /* navbar section */
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .navbar-collapse {
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }

  .brand-and-toggler {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
  }

  .nav-item {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
  }

  .nav-link {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  /* home page */
  .home .row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2rem;
  }

  .home .row > div {
    height: calc(100vh - 73px);
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .home .row-left {
    text-align: left;
  }

  .home .img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: unset;
  }

  .home .img-border {
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: var(--transition);
    border-radius: unset;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .home .img-border:hover {
    transform: translateY(-14px);
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* footer */
  .footer .row {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }

  .footer .row .col {
    text-align: left;
  }

  .footer .col:first-child .text {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .social-links {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .footer-links a .fas {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: you are right, although I assume he will copy paste and compare both css

Comment: I added the 3 closing brackets, its still giving me a parse error on the same line for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an end bracket on your mediaquery right at

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
```

section, after this

```
.footer-links a .fas {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: well on several places actually a css media query scope should be ended where it is defined